# Read dropdown list contents in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here is a dropdown which I'm trying to read, from an Excel File (.xlsx) using Apache POI Library.

[DropDown List Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE6yN.png)

I browsed through the Apache POI Documentation and got a basic idea of how to proceed -

1. Get `List` of `XSSFValidations` from the sheet using `getDataValidations()`. Let's call it **validationsList**
2. Iterate over each `XSSFValidation` in the `List` and retrieve contents by calling the methods `getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues()` on the returned List (i.e. *validationsList*).

Here is the complete code I wrote for this functionality -

```
 CellReference ref = new CellReference("D17");
        Row r = userOperationInput_Sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        if (r != null) {
            Cell dropDownCell = r.getCell(ref.getCol());

            if (dropDownCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                System.out.println(dropDownCell.getStringCellValue());


                validationsList = userOperationInput_Sheet.getDataValidations();
                System.out.println("List Size : "+ validationsList.size());
                if (validationsList.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("No Validations Found");
                } else {
                    for (XSSFDataValidation myValidation : validationsList) {
                        System.out.println("Found Validation");
                        listValues = myValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();
                    }

                }

            }
```

Even though I clearly see a drop-down present at D17, whose String Value is being printed each time I run it, it still prints `No Validations Found` every time I try to get the List of XSSFValidations.

Any suggestions ? What am I missing here ?

**EDIT** - changed the name of List variable in my problem description to match what I wrote in the code, to avoid any confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the data of dropdowns from the below :

```
 CTDataValidations ctDataValidations = ((XSSFSheet) sheet)
    .getCTWorksheet().getDataValidations();
```

If you had found any other solution Please post it here. It will be of great help as well thanks!